# Use of assignment operators inside an 'if' condition in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

If I use assignment operators or output functions inside the *if* condition, why is it taken as a "true" Boolean value?

For example, I do

```
if(cout << "a"){cout << "c";}
```

Or

```
if(int x=7){cout << "c";}
```

Or even

```
if(6){cout << "c";}
```

the outputs *are* indeed, "c" and "c" and "c" in each case. But we were told that, inside the *if* condition, we have to use an expression that finally evaluates to a Boolean value, like 1 or 0.

So what is the piece of information I am missing?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the bool value `true` or `false`. It just has to be [contextually convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) to bool. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if .

Comment: `int x=7` isn't assignment.  it is initialization.

Comment: @NathanOliver agreed (comment removed) but it compiles, live: https://godbolt.org/g/dSef3y  Now trying to work out why.

Comment: @RichardCritten Consider `if (auto opt = something_returning_optional()) { ... }`. That's valid and has been valid for a long time

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, it will compile.  The initialized variable is then converted to a bool and checked.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks - still kind of strange `if(int x=7; int y=0){x=x;y=y}` is good

Comment: @RichardCritten That is something C++17 introduced.  Before you could only do `if(type name = initializer)` and `name` would be evaluated.  Now, in C++17, you could do `if(type name = initializer; some_condition)` but since `some_condition` can be `type name = initializer` you can declare another variable and evaluate that variable.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah the magic of _init-statement_ in selection statements #C++17

Answer (score 3):

In each case the expression is converted to a bool. The value of this bool is true in the three cases that you use (it may not always be true).

```
if(cout << "a"){cout << "c";}
```

In this case the expression:

```
   cout << "a"
```

If find the `operator<<(std::ostream&, char const*)` definition you will find that the return value is `std::ostream&`. So this will return a reference to the `cout` object (of type std::ostream). The stream object has a boolean conversion method `explicit bool()` which can be used to convert the object to bool. The result of this depends on the state of the object (if it is in a bad (failing) state it will return false).

So here you are checking that the last operation on the stream worked. If it does then print "c". This is commonly used on input streams to validate user intput.

```
int val;
if (std::cin >> val) {
    if (std::cout << "A value was correctly read\n") {
        // Add response worked.
    }
    else
    {
        // Something bad happened to std::cout
    }
}
```

In the other cases you use int variables. These can be implicitly converted to bool. If the value is non zero then it is true (otherwise false).

Answer (score 1):

Every value inside a condition (or with Boolean conversion) will give you true, unless it equal to 0.

```
(6)            returns => 6              != 0            => true
(x = 7)        returns => 7              != 0            => true
(cout << "aa") returns => ostream object.
                          bool context so calls `ostream::operator bool()`
                          If the stream is in good state => true
                          Otherwise                      => false
```

In C you can see it with `NULL` with this declaration:

```
#define NULL 0
```

which means that if an pointer equal to `NULL` it will return you a false in a Boolean conversion.

Examples in C++ for boolean expressions:

```
int a, b, *c;
char d;
bool e;

a = 0;
b = 2;
c = nullptr;

e = a; // false
e = b - 2; // false
e = c; // false

c = &a;
e = c; // true
e = b; // true
e = a + 1; // true
e = b ^ b; // false

d = 0;
e = d; // false
d = '0';
e = d; // true
```

Comment: In C++11 streams convert to `bool`, not `void*`.

Comment: `nullptr` does not "return 0". In fact, its entire purpose for being is _not_ to evaluate to `0`, since that was a common problem with the macro `NULL`.

Comment: How `NULL` is related to the question?

Comment: @Slava the OP saw only `true` cases. I want to show also `false` case example.

Answer (score 0):

In all the cases you've shown, it's still true that you've provided an expression that eventually is convertible to `bool`. If you look at the [`<<` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) of `std::cout` and similar `ostream`s, you'll see they all return a reference to the same stream. This stream also defines a [conversion to `bool` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which is *implicitly* called in a context where a `bool` is expected. This particular conversion returns `true` if the stream has no errors. Secondly, `int x=7` is an initialization, and it returns the value that `x` was just initialized with; `7` in this case. `int` in C++ can be implicitly cast to bool to be `true` if it's not zero, which is why both `7` and `6` evaluate to true in the second and third examples.

Comment: Please note that the assignment operator is not called here.  `if(int x=7){cout << "c";}` is syntatic sugar for `{ int x=7; if(x){cout << "c";}}`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in elementary terms please? I am new to Computer science, almost only a week. What are streams and all?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal I would start at the beginning of a [recommended C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn about basic language constructs and classes. As a beginner in school, the details of how `cout` probably won't matter, but as you get comfortable and if it interests you, read about implicit conversions and operator overloading.

Comment: In general, C++  has lots of hidden surprises that can haunt your code if you're not careful. Good practice and sticking to neat style and convention will keep things easy and predictable.